# Detecting duplicates in a number (Python)

Tags: python

I am currently working on a small project that involves analysing ballot papers and determining the winning candidate based on the number of votes they receive. The voting system is unusual. For example, if there are four candidates the vote could look like this: 2341 (2 for the first candidate, 3 for the second candidate etc.). However, if the vote looks like this: 2334 it is invalid, the same number cannot be used twice in the vote.
I was wondering if there is a way to check for duplicate numbers within a number. I already have a solution, however it does not work for all of my test cases.

Current Code:

```
voteListString = ['2314', '4432', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431'] # 4432 should get removed (it doesn't)
for i, voteString in enumerate(voteListString):
        newI = i+1
        duplicateCheck = voteString.count(f"{newI}")
        if duplicateCheck > 1:
            voteInt = int(voteString)
            voteList.remove(f"{voteInt}")
            spoiltBallots += 1
        else:
            validVoteList.append(voteString)
```

The code above is a for loop that loops through a list of votes that have been converted to a string. It then counts the number of times 'i' appears in the vote, if it appears more than once it will remove it from the list. This only works for one of my test cases. If there is a better way to do this I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `set`

```py
def is_valid(vote):
    return len(set(vote)) == len(vote)

print(is_valid('4432')) # False
print(is_valid('1234')) # True
```

---

```py
voteListString = ['2314', '4432', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431']

new_vote_list_string = list(filter(is_valid, voteListString))

print(new_vote_list_string)
```

```
['2314', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431']
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can try using `set` like this

```
   def check_duplicates(voteString):
      if len(set(voteString)) != len(voteString):
          print(f"there is (are) duplicate(s) in {voteString }")
      else:
          print(f"there is (are) no duplicate(s) in {voteString }")
```

Checking:

```
check_duplicates('2341')
check_duplicates('2334')
```

> there is (are) no duplicate(s) in 2341

> there is (are) duplicate(s) in 2334

Answer (score 2):

How about using sets:

```
voteListString = ['2314', '4432', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431'] 
spoiltBallots = 0
validVoteList = []
for v in voteListString:
    s = set(v)
    if (len(s)<4):
        spoiltBallots += 1
    else:
        validVoteList.append(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the length of set of a word to the length of the word and remove if unequal:

```
voteListString = ['2314', '4432', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431']
for vote in voteListString:
    if len(set(vote)) < len(vote):
        voteListString.remove(vote)
print(voteListString)
#['2314', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431']
```

Answer (score 2):

OK. too many answers using sets (which is the best way to go), so, for variety here is a solution using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

votes = ['2314', '4432', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431']
for vote in votes:
    if len(Counter(vote)) < len(vote):
        print(f'{vote} contains duplicates')

# 4432 contains duplicates
```

`Counter` has more overhead than a simple set, so here is the same solution using sets:

You could use a set to remove duplicate digits from a vote string and exclude those that have length != the length of the vote string:

```
votes = ['2314', '4432', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431']
for vote in votes:
    if len(set(vote)) < len(vote):
        print(f'{vote} contains duplicates')

# 4432 contains duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the sorted digits in each vote string to the list of candidates will not only validate that each digit is distinct but also that there is the right number of selections and that they are valid digits.

```
candidates     = sorted('1234') 
voteListString = ['2314','4432','4312','1243','1234','2431',
                  '123','2354','12334'] 
validVoteList  = [v for v in voteListString if sorted(v) == candidates]
spoiltBallots  = len(voteListString) - len(validVoteList)


print(validVoteList) # ['2314', '4312', '1243', '1234', '2431']
print(spoiltBallots) # 4
```